# Unable to install nodejs on my computer

Tags: node.js

I am using windows and when I took reference to download node js from  [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.install/0.6.10). When I write this line

> C:> cinst nodejs.install -Version 0.6.10

in CMD it gives an error

> C:>cinst nodejs.install -Version 0.6.10
>   'cinst' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I don't know how to install node js.I also have a question that if I install node js version say v0.10.26 will the programs made with `previous versions(say 0.9)` will work on `0.10`

Comment: You can install node.js on http://nodejs.org/ (for older versions http://nodejs.org/dist/) and also you can install "cinst" on https://chocolatey.org/ (using command prompt, explained in the home page). Newer versions probably support older version apps, unless you set the version to use on your app exclusively.

Comment: @Musa I clicked on http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.10/ but unable to get how to download it.

Comment: You can download and run node-v0.6.10.msi on that directory @TruePS

Comment: @MusaHafalir what about my second question  if I install node js version say v0.10.26 will the programs made with previous versions(say 0.9) will work on 0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that your cmd session can't find cinst.  To use cinst, you have to install the package manager from http://chocolatey.org/

If you just want to get Node.js running though, there's a Windows installer at http://nodejs.org/download/ or you can just hit the big green Install button at http://nodejs.org/

*Summarizing comments:*

All of the versions are maintained and available under http://nodejs.org/dist/, 0.6.10 can be found at: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.10/ and you can get the Windows installer by downloading the .msi file.

As for whether there might be breaking changes from version to version, most code moves forward just fine, but testing is always a good idea.  Some packages will specify a specific version in their package.json file, but most will just request a version greater than a certain point in the engines element like:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=0.6.10" } }
```

Comment: Firstly I want to install only Version 0.6.10 and what about my second question if I install node js version say v0.10.26 will the programs made with previous versions(say 0.6) will work on 0.10